# How to run a program 100 times in R?

Tags: r

The script calls another script that contains functions and then has a bunch of random vectors generated that run through the functions and ends up giving the difference between the two means.

I want to run the script 100 times and store the difference between the means in a growing vector? Any help is appreciated.

Here is a basic idea of the script.
source('Functions.R')
bunch of numbers generated and tests

```
difference.means=mean.t-mean.c
mat.means=matrix(data=difference.means, nrow=1, ncol=100)
```

Comment: Sorry the source, bunch of numbers, difference.means, and mat.means should all be on different lines

Comment: look at `?replicate`

Comment: The name of the script is Exp. 1.R so I've tried varying versions of something like replicate(100, source('Exp. 1.R')). It will run a few times replacing the entire 100 long vector with the new difference and then gives an error:                                                                                          Error in hist.default(resid.c, seq(-0.5, 0.5, 0.03), col = rgb(0, 0, 0,  : 
  some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'                        Could I use a for loop to iterate through and replace each element ?

Comment: Rather than a script that creates a variable, you need to turn it into a function that returns a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replicate` can run a function a number of times set by the user.

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:100, 10))
colMeans(sample(df1))
  X9   X6   X1  X10   X2   X3   X7   X5   X4   X8 
85.5 55.5  5.5 95.5 15.5 25.5 65.5 45.5 35.5 75.5 

replicate(5, colMeans(sample(df1)))
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
X6  55.5 35.5 75.5 85.5 85.5
X10 95.5 65.5 65.5 45.5 75.5
X8  75.5 95.5 25.5 35.5  5.5
X7  65.5 75.5 35.5 25.5 65.5
X3  25.5 25.5 15.5 55.5 35.5
X5  45.5  5.5  5.5 65.5 95.5
X4  35.5 15.5 45.5 75.5 15.5
X1   5.5 45.5 55.5 15.5 25.5
X9  85.5 55.5 95.5  5.5 55.5
X2  15.5 85.5 85.5 95.5 45.5
```

Therefore, in the general case:

```
replicate(<ntimes>, <func>)
[1]<func> (1) output
[2]<func> (2) output
...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. For replicate it seems you need a function to evaluate 100 times. My point of confusion is the difference between running the entire script and running one function 100 times.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the first few lines of your code. because the part you've added can be wrapped in a function

Comment: I made this. dif.means=function(resid.c,resid.t){mean(resid.c)-mean(resid.t)} then replicate(100,dif.means) but this replicates the actual text 100 times. The layout of the code is:     source('Functions.R') which calls another script that has three functions and starting parameters. made random data points using runif(20). and then based on where the data points fall in a grid it reassigns the parameters and runs it through the functions. I have two groups and end up taking an ANOVA test and getting the means of the residuals. So basically it should run the whole thing 100 times. Thanks

Comment: You aren't giving anything that can't be wrapped in `replicate`. `masterfunction <- function() { func1() commands; func2() commands ...} replicate(100, masterfunction)`

Comment: If you don't want to do that, wrap the whole thing in a slower `for` loop. Something like `for(i in 1:100) { x[i] <- runif(20); func1(x[i]); func2(x[i])...` That way the randomization process will happen at each iteration. You just have to remember to store the results somewhere.

Comment: Great! Thanks the for loop works, now I just have to store them which I planned on doing by making a vector of length 100 like mat.means=numeric(length=100) followed by the for loop with the script in it and then before the for loop ends putting in mat.means[i]=mean(resid.c)-mean(resid.t) but when I call mat.means it shows up as 100 zeros. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Make sure `mat.means = numeric(100)` is on the outside of the for loop. Or else it will erase what you put in it each time it loops.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try `mat.means = c()` on the outside of the for loop.

Comment: It is outside the loop. I have it display the answer each time and it runs through 100 times but for some reason is not storing them.

Comment: This is why it is advised over and over to give a reproducible example. It can be so many things. You may have a comma in the wrong place. If you can't simplify your problem to a smaller example and post it. We will be on here guessing all day.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I got it now, it was a silly error in multiple for loops.

Comment: ok cheers. keep at it